# How to use a custom reducer's state as a permanent filter in a <List>?

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom reducer and a connected component to change its state. Now I'd like to use this state as a permanent filter on List elements. 
I understand the List elements are connected to the redux-state, so I hope I'm able to access it through the List component's props, but couldn't find a way how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `List` component is connected but not yours.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const MyList = ({ is_published, ...props }) => (
    <List {...props} filter={{ is_published }}>

    </List>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    is_published: state.myCustomReducer.is_published,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, undefined)(MyList);
```

**Edit:**

Just found out we don't update data when this prop change. This is a bug and you can open an issue about it.

In the mean time, here's a workaround:
Create a [custom saga](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas) listening to whatever action you use alongside your custom reducer (I'll call it `SET_IS_PUBLISHED` for my example). This custom saga should `put` the `changeListParams` action creator from `react-admin` with your filter.

It will probably looks like this (not tested):

```
import { takeEvery, put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { changeListParams } from 'react-admin'
import { SET_IS_PUBLISHED } from './isPublished'

const getCurrentListParams = (state, resource) => {
    const resourceState = state.admin.resources[resource]
    return resourceState.list.params
}

function handleSetPublished({ payload }) {
    const currentParams = yield select(getCurrentListParams)
    const newParams = {
        // Keep the current params
        ...currentParams,
        // Override the filter
        filter: {
            // Keep the current filter
            ...currentParams.filter,
            // Only override the is_published
            is_published: payload
        }
    }
    // Dispatch the action for the `posts` resource
    yield put(changeListParams('posts', newParams))
}

export default function* () {
    yield takeEvery(SET_IS_PUBLISHED, handleSetPublished)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The redux state doesn't reach the filter for some reason. The filter works fine if I enter a number there (the state is an id number). Connection to the custom reducer state works fine in a custom component I made to try it out as I'm new to redux

Comment: Okay, this should include all the relevant code: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxmxyvoxw3

Comment: There are a few comments clarifying things in the code. Also included is the file BuildingFilter I've used to test that the reducer works. It does. I have also tried creating a function to be exported from that file and used on BusAdapterList. What we want out of this is that we have loads of different resources related to a building and we'd like to be able to select the building from the Dashboard so you don't need to have a separate filter on each List page.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I'll open an issue about this - thanks for your assistance. I've been doing other stuff and getting back to this problem. 
One more question:  You said " we don't update data when this prop change".  Does this mean the filter should work on the initial value? I tried to set the initial state of my reducer by calling it with ComponentWillMount in the component I'm using to control the state. The component is on my Dashboard. The state is set, but isn't used on the filter.
Anyways, I'll try your workaround, hope it will solve my problem :)

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work, after [the fix](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2188). The list re-renders when state changes, but the filter values that get passed in the api call are still the old ones. Did anyone else try this?

Comment: I setup a codesandbox for this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/r656z506p). I have two elements in the list and the permanent filter is the id. The default value is 0. When clicking on the "Change id to 1" checkbox at the top, the state changes to 1, so the list should display post with id 1. The nextProps value is correct. However, I get an error in the console, not sure why.

In my real application there’s no error, but the list is still filtered by the old state value. On each subsequent checkbox click, the list gets filtered with the previous value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just to bring this into 2021, you can use the useSelector redux hook to get hold of your custom state:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const MyCustomThing = (props) => {
  const is_published = useSelector(state => state.customState.is_published);
}
```

For completeness, react-admin provides a customReducers prop to its `<Admin>` component so you can extend the redux state with your custom values:

```
const customStateReducer = (customState = { is_published: false }, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === 'IS_PUBLISHED') customState.is_published = payload.is_published;
  return customState;
}

<Admin customReducers={{ customState: customStateReducer }} ...>
etc
```